# Global variable for debug options and logging in GAE Python

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine

I'd like a global variable to determine if I'm in debug mode or not. Is that what `__debug__` is for? How do I set/read it on Google App Engine?

If I use `logging.debug()`, will that automatically be turned off if I don't run the app with `debug=True`?

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(# ...
                                        debug=True)
```

Comment: I too haven't figured out how to know if I'm in debug mode. Were you ever able to locate a solution to this issue?

Comment: I've improved your title, I hope you don't mind, it's just that I *three* would really like an actual answer to this!

Answer (score 5):

`__debug__` is built-in constant defined by Python.  The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html) say this: "This constant is true if Python was not started with an -O option. Assignments to **debug** are illegal and raise a SyntaxError. See also the assert statement."

The `debug=True` you pass to `webapp.WSGIApplication` is completely separate.

Neither of these will affect `logging.debug()` either.  You can use [`logging.setLevel()`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) to  control how `logging.debug()` is handled.

Comment: logging.setlevel isn't advisable for App Engine - the logger in production logs everything into separate logs, separated by level anyway.

Comment: This would be improved if you summarised what *should* be done. 1) Leave `__debug__` alone, 2) Pass `debug=True` to webapp, 3) .. What *is* advisable @NickJohnson?